# Zend\View\Helper\Url resolves no route

Tags: php, zend-framework2, url-routing

i have trouble with resolving routes via the ZendFramework2 url view helper

```
Zend\View\Helper\Url
```

when i try to resolve my route with:

```
{$route['action']   = 'install'}
{$route['id']       = $this->escapeHtml($project->__get('id'))}
{$href              = $this->url('projects', $route)}
```

(i'm using smarty3 as templating)

My routing configuration looks like this:

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Projects\Controller\Projects',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'projects' => array(
            'type'    => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/projects',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => 'Projects\Controller\Projects',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'install' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/install/[:projectId]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'projectId' => '[0-9]+'
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Projects\Controller\Projects',
                            'action' => 'install',
                            'projectId' => '0'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'type'    => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
...
```

The helper just can resolve my route to /projects
he does not see the child routes.

After some var_dumping i saw that my TreeRouteStack has a Part object having my desired routes.

```
Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part#133 (9) { 
    protected $route => class Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal#132 (2) { 
        protected $route => string(9) "/projects" 
        protected $defaults => array(2) { 
            'controller' => string(28) "Projects\Controller\Projects" 
            'action' => string(5) "index" 
        }
    } 
    protected $mayTerminate => bool(true) 
    protected $childRoutes => NULL 
    protected $baseUrl => NULL 
    protected $requestUri => NULL 
    protected $routes => class Zend\Mvc\Router\PriorityList#134 (4) { 
        protected $routes => array(2) { 
            'install' => array(3) { ... } 
            'defaults' => array(3) { ... } 
        } 
        protected $serial => int(2) 
        protected $count => int(2) 
        protected $sorted => bool(false) 
    }..
```

Unfortunaly i declared my routes as childroutes, but the Part does not have any childs. The routes im looking for, are within the $routes variable.
What i am doing wrong in my routing that its now splitted wrong? And therefore not accesible by the url-helper.

Edit:

If i resolve my routes without the helper i can access the /projects/install/[id] route.

Comment: The child route is located at `projects/install`, so you should be using `$this->url('projects/install', array('id' => $id));`,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Crisp helping to find the solution. The "projects/install" is necessary, but there was one more error.

I defined:

```
'constraints' => array(
    'projectId' => '[0-9]+'
),
```

in my route and only

```
array('id' => $id)
```

in my url helper. Then the helper could not put the given id in the route.

So the solution (for me) is

```
$this->url('projects/install', array('projectId' => $id));
```

or in Smarty:

```
{$route['projectId']= $this->escapeHtml($project->__get('id'))}
{$href              = $this->url('projects/install', $route)}
```